# Download smaller image sizes through Podio API (PHP)

Tags: podio

How to download smaller image sizes from Podio API. I'm able to download the original image (with get_raw()), but not the other sizes. Is this even possible?

PHP API Clients get_raw method has $size property:

```
public function get_raw($size = null) {
    return Podio::get($this->get_download_link($size), array(), 
    array('file_download' => true))->body;
}
```

but any $size will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify which `$size` you have used?

It seems that `get_download_link` method will work for you better (https://github.com/podio/podio-php/blob/master/models/PodioFile.php#L27 )
And it should accept `$size` values from https://developers.podio.com/doc/files documentation page (one of: `medium`, `badge`, `extra_large` for images attached to items)

Comment: `get_download_link` seems to be a private method that `get_raw ` calls. If I call `get_raw('medium')`, it just returns `Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError Request URL`.

Comment: can you please share full example and full error message? Also, what image you are trying to download? (is it attachment, avatar, item image)